# Increase the execution time of php within a browser

Tags: php

I have a php script that processes so many requests and it takes about 1 and half hour to finish.

Now I accessing the script using the browser like so.

```
http://localhost/app.php
```

It runs curl requests, write files, and yeah it takes long. But what happened if it takes too long is that it throws a fatal error.

I haven't tried it yet, what I have tried so far is the maximum execution time like so:

```
init_set('max_execution_time', 4800)
```

What I have seen that can help is this, but haven't tried yet, is this the one I am looking

```
set_time_limit(4800) // this is in seconds right?
```

Comment: Such a script should be accessed from a command line, *not* the browser. Your browser will give up and there's nothing you can do to stop that.

Comment: bah really? the problem is that in the commandline, I timedout because of the ClientAliveInterval is a bit low, and I am on a shared server, the hosts told me, I cannot configure it higher

Comment: You should try breaking down your script into smaller pieces then. Shared hosts can be very picky about long-running scripts (and for good reason!) and usually kill scripts that run longer than 30 seconds (although if I ran a shared server I'd make the time limit 2 seconds - a script that runs longer than that needs optimising!)

Answer (score 0):

try this **set_time_limit(0);** and check with server admin has blocked you or give less size(kB) of per request. and also check memory_limit.And your IT team has access to give you less permission